# Javascript error in content display " Cannot set property "display" of undefined "

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem with some javascript, that I found as a solution for content switching.

On the webpage: [www.enyx.sk/cubecraft](http://www.enyx.sk/cubecraft), when you load the page you should get the content of the first story or tab "O nas" but after the page loads the content of this page is not shown and you have to click the menu link so that it shows...

I've checked the code after the site loaded and got the following error : Uncaught TypError: Cannot set property "display" of undefined.

Just to be clear I am a fresh beginner in JS and this is a solution for content switching I found online. It worked fine until now and I can not figure out what causes the first content to hide...

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue in below code snippet. because firstChild does not return the div that you expect.

```
var firstone=document.getElementById('stories').firstChild;
if (firstone.nodeType != 1) {firstone = firstone.nextSibling;}
firstone.style.display="block";
}
```

instead of that try using this.

```
document.getElementById('stories').getElementsByClassName("story")[0].style.display= 'block'
```

It will work :-)

**EDIT**

```
var firstone=document.getElementById('stories').getElementsByClassName("story")[0]
    if (firstone.nodeType != 1) {firstone = firstone.nextSibling;}
    firstone.style.display="block";
```